# Detect when page is reloaded with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, mutation-observers

Im trying to monitor the changes in a website with puppeteer and MutationObserver.

To do this, i have to evaluate javascript code to inject the mutation observer object.

My problem arrives when the page is reloaded every 'n' time, my mutation observer is not injected any more.

I need to detect when the page reloads itself to inject again the mutation observer.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

//Ejecucion de Puppeteer
puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
console.log('Running script..')
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('mywebsite');

//Wait for my selector
await page.waitForSelector('my-selector')

//Create a function to get data in puppeteer context
await page.exposeFunction('puppeteerLogMutation',(param1) => {
    console.log('----NEW MUTATION----');
    console.log(param1);   
});

//Inject Mutation Observer
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
        mutationList.forEach((mutation)=> {
            //Do something with the mutation detected
            //Send data to puppeteer context
            puppeteerLogMutation(mutation.type)
        })
    });
    //MutationObserver configure
    const observerOptions = {
                      attributes: true,
                      childList: true,
                      subtree: true,
                      characterData: true,
                      attributeOldValue: true,
                      characterDataOldValue: true
                      };
//Mutation observer object execution
    observer.observe(target, observerOptions);
}`
```

Obviously when the page is reloaded my injection doesnt work anymore so i im trying to detect when the page reload to inject again the observer.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args) can help instead?

Comment: it seems work, im trying some tests, i will return in a few hours if its definitely working. Thanks

Comment: Its totally working. Now, i have another problem... Do u know how can i pass data generate on evaluate to evaluateonnewdocument?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try to [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) and call it from evaluateonnewdocument function to get updated data transferred from evaluate to Node.js context.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty could you please share the solution and how to use it, it's confusing

Answer (score 0):

The following code will insert a button inside the page represented by this url
`'https://www.google.com/'` the button will be added back again in the page in case of reload : *the browser will crash if refresh is spammed due to a NavigationError*

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

const launchOptions = { 
    headless: false, 
    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', // because we are using puppeteer-core we must define this option
    args: ['--start-maximized'] 
     
};
  
const BTN_CSS = `
 <style>
     .btn-next-url {
         position: absolute;
         top: 50px;
         left: 70px;
 
         height: 30px;
         width: 70px;
 
         font-size: 20px;
         font-weight: bold;
 
         color: white;
         background-color: red;
 
         border: none;
         border-radius: 5px;
 
         cursor: pointer;
 
         opacity: 50%;
     }
 
     .btn-next-url:hover {
         opacity: 100%
     }
 </style>`;
 
const BTN_HTML = `${BTN_CSS}
<button id="next-page-btn" class="btn-next-url" title="navigate to next url" onclick="( () => alert('button clicked') )()">>></button>`;
 
async function runTest() {    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0]; // use the default tab

    await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
   
    // expose a function in page context  (the function will be executed in nodejs context but can be called from inside page context)
    await page.exposeFunction("insertButtonInPage", () => insertButtonInPage(page)); 
    // function provided here will be executed in the page context 
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument( () => insertButtonInPage()); // the button is added in page here    

    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
 
    await delay(15000);
    await browser.close();
}

async function insertButtonInPage(page) {
    await page.waitForSelector('body');

    page.$eval('body', (body, btn_html) => { // adds a button in the page
            body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', btn_html);
    }, BTN_HTML);
}

const delay = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

runTest();
```

**The important parts are:**

```
await page.exposeFunction("insertButtonInPage", () => insertButtonInPage(page));
```

This **expose** the function `insertButtonInPage()` that is currently used to add the button in the page and allow it's use from **inside page context**.  [Page.exposeFunction()](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.exposefunction)

Next is the call to [Page.evaluateOnNewDocument()](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluateonnewdocument)

```
 await page.evaluateOnNewDocument( () => insertButtonInPage());
```

This **adds** a function (executed in page context) which would be invoked in one of the following scenarios:

- whenever the page is navigated
- whenever the child frame is attached or navigated. In this case, the function is invoked in the context of the newly attached frame.

> The function is invoked after the document was created but before any
> of its scripts were run.